# Selecting data within JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'd like to pull data using SQL in Postgres but would like to go into the JSON result and only extract the data I need.

If I write (in Valentina studio):

```
Select "data" from "cars"
```

The first row looks like:

```
[{"Model": "Golf", "Make": "VW", "Engine": "2.9"}, 
{"Model": "M3", "Make": "BMW", "Engine": "3.0"}]
```

What I would like is simply:

`Golf, M3` or `"Golf", "M3"`

Then I could also use the same method for `"Make"` or `"Engine"`

Essentially I don't want my results in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
with cars(data) as (
values
    ('[
        {"Model": "Golf", "Make": "VW", "Engine": "2.9"}, 
        {"Model": "M3", "Make": "BMW", "Engine": "3.0"}
    ]'::json)
)

select 
    elem->>'Model' as model,
    elem->>'Make' as make,
    elem->>'Engine' as engine
from cars,
lateral json_array_elements(data) elem

 model | make | engine 
-------+------+--------
 Golf  | VW   | 2.9
 M3    | BMW  | 3.0
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT string_agg(x->>'Model', ',')
FROM cars
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      jsonb_array_elements(data) x
GROUP BY cars;

┌────────────┐
│ string_agg │
├────────────┤
│ Golf,M3    │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I also got what I wanted (and melted it the way I was planning to do) with:

```
    select obj->'Model' as model, obj->'Make' as make, 
obj->'Engine' as engine from data n, jsonb_array_elements(n.DATA) as obj
```

from the above I can also use:

```
select 
    elem->>'Model' as model,
    elem->>'Make' as make ,
    elem->>'Engine' as engine
from cars,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(data) elem;
```

Thanks for the help!